# jQuery in-viewport not detecting multiple videos

Tags: javascript, jquery, video

I am using the jQuery plugin `isInViewport` [jQuery isInViewport](https://github.com/zeusdeux/isInViewport) to control the playing and pausing of two videos on a single page once they're scrolled in & out of view.

The only way I was able to get it to work was explicitly checking each video ID with two if-statements.

**The following works:**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ( $("video#one").is( ':in-viewport')) {
     $("video#one")[0].play();
  } else {
     $("video#one")[0].pause();
  }

  if ( $("video#two").is( ':in-viewport')) {
     $("video#two")[0].play();
  } else {
     $("video#two")[0].pause();
  }
});
```

However, that's inefficient. I may add more videos down the road. Doesn't make sense to have to adjust the JS each time I change videos.

This is what I am going for.. however, once video 1 is scrolled into view, it triggers the second video (which is off-screen) to begin playing as well.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $("video").each(function() {
     if ( $("video").is( ':in-viewport')) {
        $("video")[0].play();
     } else {
        $("video")[0].pause();
     }
  });
});
```

**How can I adjust the each function to play & pause my videos on 1 page, regardless of how many there are?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely in your **each** function you are referring to ALL videos again and again. You should be able to solve this by using **THIS** instead.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $("video").each(function() {
     if ( $(this).is( ':in-viewport')) {
        $(this)[0].play();
     } else {
        $(this)[0].pause();
     }
  });
});
```

Comment: Even if `$("video").is( ':in-viewport')` is `true`, shouldn't the first video play only `$("video")[0].play();` ?